# VisualStudio 2013 list all NuGet packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

I have a mvc 5 web project with a number of NuGet packages installed (like email, log, pagedlist etc).

In a new similar project I would like to install the same NuGet packages. How can I in the old project list all installed NuGet packages?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can find a `packages.config` file in the old project's root directory.
2. You can copy it to the new project.
3. If you go to Tools -> NuGet Packet Manager -> Packet manager settings and check `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` and the other check box that states `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` it will download it for you next time you build.

Comment: This will work but I have a couple of packages in the old project that I have no need for in the new project. 
I list of installed packages and the a manual enter of wanted packages in the new project is what I am looking for.
The packages.config gic me all, including, related packages. I would like to only see root packages. Ex) Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi installes up to 6 packages.

Comment: If they really are a couple of packages I suggest removing them manually afterwards, otherwise the work of finding what the dependencies are is harder. The package dependencies is described in dependencies section in https://www.nuget.org/packages/your-package. I don't know if there is an automatic way of getting this info from the NuGet console

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all installed nuget packages for the project take a look at this one.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2014/08/19/micro-blog-how-to-list-installed-nuget-packages-from-package-manager-console-and-be-able-to-read-them.aspx

You might also want to enable nuget package restore to restore the packages when rebuilding your project/s.
Here's another link for you - http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Comment: Can you please add the relevant information to your answer? Link-only answers are generally not recommended :)

Comment: I just edited it, the link has all the information to answer the question. :)

Comment: Yes, but if that page goes offline in the future, your answer becomes useless. If you add the relevant pieces here, people can still benefit from your answer.

Comment: It's not only that the linked page may go away. How can anyone know that a raw link contains the answer to the question, or that it's the correct one? For that reason, raw links should be avoided as well. Markdown makes it extremely easy to create linked text

Comment: @projectzerotohero The thanks are on you :) Upvoted.

Comment: Also noted that one @PanagiotisKanavos. :) Thanks :)

Comment: PM> Get-Package
Gives me all installed packages. Almost what I want. Some packages comes with the start of a new mvc project. Like jquery and bootstrap. Others are dependency packages. "Install-Package WebApi" gives up to 6 packages installed. They are easy to spot since they start with same schema name and has same version, but others can have different schema names and versions. I would like to list only "root" packages.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the root folder of your original project find a `packages.config` file. Copy its contents to your new project, same file name.
2. Go to Visual Studio > Tools > Package Manager Settings > General
3. Enable "Allow Nuget to download..." and "Automatically check for missing..."

Now build your new project

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are partially correct.

The first part is true. The *packages.config* file lists all packages that are used by the project.

However, all the answers about using Package Restore are incorrect. Package Restore will download any missing packages, however it is **NOT** the same as installing a package into a project. It will not add references, run any install.ps1 scripts, or add files, modify .config, etc. Package Restore simply downloads missing packages. It is assumed that the packages were already installed to the project.

In order for the packages to be correctly installed in your new project, open the Package Manager console, then type:

```
Update-Package -ProjectName MyProjectName -Reinstall
```

This will force NuGet to run through the install process and correctly install the package into your project.